# Searching And Filtering in an ojTable

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

What is the best way to search a set of rows once an ojTable is rendered with complete data from database. My current implementation takes the search arguments as query Parameters and then pass them to the backend and then return the result back to UI from db.

But I want to shift the search and filter implementation logic to the front end to reduce the time taken. Does ojet provide any inbuild feature to make the search and filter easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Filtering the records in a table by the search criteria: http://jsjim.blogspot.in/2016/03/filtering-oracle-jet.html

Answer (score 0):

ojTable doesn't provide an inbuild searching or filtering feature as of the latest version v2.2.0.

However, you could build your own by using a [knockout observable array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) as an ArraytableDataSource. Then you can search or filter directly on the observable array.  [Here is an OJET example](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=table&demo=observableArrayTable) shows you how to use ko.observableArray with ojTable.

Comment: Any plans for adding searching and filtering feature like oracle apex ? I do not see any references made to this in jet cookbook